# How to edit/add/remove field of default login, registration, profile etc... forms

Tags: default

Hi I am new in Joomla and i am trying to change the way my default forms look. For example, in the login form i would like to replace the default username field with an e-mail field, or in the user profile I would like to delete the confirm-email address field and add an image field (so every user can have his/her picture there).

How can i do this? I have searched online and can't find an answer. I have tried overwriting default files, searching for tutorials and still can't find the answer.

Help is greatly appreciated.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

For something like this you are going to need to do this in a few steps and have a couple of options.

To make things easy I would recommend looking into something like JomSocial or Community Builder as most of the functionality you are looking for seems to be built in as far as avatars and custom registration pages. You other alternative is to override the Joomla Profile plugin as well as create a custom module for uploading/displaying avatar images for logged in users.

Hope this gives you a bit of guidance. I personally would recommend CB, I have used it in the past and it is very highly customizable.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the RSForm component & its registration plugin for this purpose.

Some fields are mandatory for the Joomla registration form, but you can add a variety of fields indefinitely and arbitrarily.